# why can't the void output() read the value inputted from void input()? the void output() can't display the player[x].playerName

Tags: c++, function

i am new to C++. i want to know how to make the inputted value be read from one function to another function. thank you. i am using two different void function and struct. i can't seem to make the output function read the value from the input function specially the playerName

```
struct playerType
{
    string playerName;
    int homeRuns, numHits;
};

void input()
{
    int x;
    playerType player[2];

    for(x=0; x<2; x++)
    {
        system("cls");
        welcome();
        cout << "Input the following information:\n\n\n" 
             << "Player's name:  ";
        cin >> player[x].playerName;
        cout << "Number of home runs:  ";
        cin >> player[x].homeRuns;
        cout << "Number of hits:  ";
        cin >> player[x].numHits;
        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "PLAYER REGISTERED!!!";
    }

}

void output()
{
    int x;
    playerType player[10];
    system("cls");
    welcome();
    cout << "Player Data:\n\n";
    for(x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        cout << "Player's name:  " << player[x].playerName; 
    // why can't this one display the player[x].playerName from the input()
        cout << "\nNumber of home runs:  " << player[x].homeRuns;
        cout << "\nNumber of hits:  " << player[x].numHits;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because here you create new, local players in the output function

```
void output()
{
    int x;
    playerType player[10]; //<- here
```

You need to create them outside these functions instead (in main perhaps?) and have the functions operate on the same set of players. Now each function creates its' own player array and i guess this is not what you want.